# Lyx language problem in the captions

Tags: tables, floats, captions, lyx, languages

I'm writing a document by lyx, but I've a problem.
I setted:

1. Document->Settings->Language->"English"
2. In the Latex preamble I wrote "\documentclass[english]{book}" and "\usepackage[english]{babel}"
3. Modify->Text styl->Language ->"English"

but when I compile the pdf, in the caption of figures and tables, it writes "Figura" and "Tabella", i.e. it writes in Italian nstead of English

Does someone know how to solve?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you install more than one time, one with "for this user only" and one with "all the users"? The first step in your question is enough for me to change the label language.

Comment: What version of LyX are you using? Can you post a minimal .lyx example file? see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample